# Python requests and BeautifulSoup4 .get('href') returning absolute address when scraping from Safaribooksonline

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the contents of `<a>` tags from a web page. My code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

url = 'https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-performance-optimization/9780134985961'

req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

lessons = soup.find_all('li', class_='toc-level-1')
lesson = lessons[0]
print(lesson)
```

My page has an element: (Obtained directly from the output of my DOM inspector in firefox)...

```
<li class="toc-level-1 t-toc-level-1 js-content-uri" data-content-uri="/api/v1/book/9780134985961/chapter/LPOC_00_00_00.html">
   <a href="/library/view/linux-performance-optimization/9780134985961/LPOC_00_00_00.html" class="t-chapter" tabindex="39">Introduction</a>
   <ol>
      <li class="toc-level-2 t-toc-level-2 js-content-uri" data-content-uri="/api/v1/book/9780134985961/chapter/LPOC_00_00_00.html"><a href="/library/view/linux-performance-optimization/9780134985961/LPOC_00_00_00.html" class="t-chapter" tabindex="41">Linux Performance Optimization: Introduction</a></li>
   </ol>
</li>
```

However, when I use requests and the bs4 modules to scrape the data, with the above code, the output I get is:

```
<li class="toc-level-1 t-toc-level-1">
    <a class="t-chapter js-chapter" href="https://www.safaribooksonline.comhttps://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-performance-optimization/9780134985961/LPOC_00_00_00.html">Introduction</a>
    <ol>
        <li class="toc-level-2 t-toc-level-2">
            <a class="t-chapter js-chapter" href="https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-performance-optimization/9780134985961/LPOC_00_00_00.html">Linux Performance Optimization: Introduction</a>
        </li>
    </ol>
</li>
```

Notice the href values of the `<a>` tags? They're supposed to be relative URLs like: `/library/view/linux-performance-optimization/9780134985961/LPOC_00_00_00.html` but I get absolute ones - and that too wrong sometimes: `https://www.safaribooksonline.comhttps://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-performance-optimization/9780134985961/LPOC_00_00_00.html`.

I have no clue how the domain name gets prefixed to the link url, since only the href value is given in the original HTML, unless requests or bs4 is doing this. All my previous scripts that used this same method are also producing a similar error. Did something change on the side of the modules, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Rahul amazing insights bud, what I just described is from the output of my source code viewer in Firefox. The web console. So, that's what my browser is processing. This is the reason I'm wondering whether it's a problem with `requests` module, `bs4` or my code. 

Also, maybe next time before calling something _rubbish_, try and verify if the problem exists yourself? Oh, and they're called `absolute urls`, buddy, not _full urls_, and no website internally links using those cause they would break in case of a domain change.

Comment: OK genius. good luck. for your information source doesn't change browser to browser. I checked on both chrome and firefox. the source have full urls. bs4 doesn't change anything. it just parse. it may be that earlier the site have different soure.

Comment: I've just checked using `wget` and line 335 of HTML source really is `      <a href="https://www.safaribooksonline.comhttps://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-performance-optimization/9780134985961/LPOC_00_00_00.html" class="t-chapter js-chapter">I
.` - the problem is with safaribooksonline.com website and not with your code nor bs4 nor requests. Also most URLs on this website are absolute. I have seen a few relative URLs but not too many.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Okay, so someone might have broken their URLs? That link doesn't work! As for the kinds of links that are used - sure, depends on the developer. But I'm sure that safaribooksonline uses relative links due to [the output of my DOM inspector](https://i.imgur.com/RTKf2Qr.png)

Comment: @Rahul Of course the links don't change from browser to browser. But please see [this image](https://i.imgur.com/RTKf2Qr.png) to see what I mean.

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: This website safaribooksonline.com is horribly inconsistent - I'm not saying that the link from your screenshot has absolute URL. But most URLs on this website are absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract the URL from the `href` by using a regular expression:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys
import re

url = 'https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-performance-optimization/9780134985961'

req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')
hrefs = set()

for lesson in soup.find_all('li', class_='toc-level-1'):
    for a in lesson.find_all('a', href=True):
        found_urls = re.split(r'(https?:\/\/.*?)', a['href'])
        hrefs.add(found_urls[-2] + found_urls[-1])

for href in sorted(hrefs):
    print(href)
```

Giving you a list of found hrefs starting:

```
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-performance-optimization/9780134985961/LPOC_00_00_00.html
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-performance-optimization/9780134985961/LPOC_01_00_00.html
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-performance-optimization/9780134985961/LPOC_01_01_00.html
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-performance-optimization/9780134985961/LPOC_01_01_01.html
```

Comment: Very close to what I did.. actually got validator to filter out malformed URLs generated by BS4 from the faulty source code!